# How to set default class property value in TypeScript declaration file?

Tags: javascript, typescript

f.e., I have

```
declare class Foo extends Bar {
    foo: number
}
```

How do I declare that `foo` has a default value (or initial value) of, say, 60.

I tried

```
declare class Foo extends Bar {
    foo: number = 60
}
```

but I get an error like

```
4     foo: number = 60
                    ~~

path/to/something.js/Foo.d.ts/(4,28): error TS1039: Initializers are not allowed in ambient contexts.
```

Comment: Why do you need to set a default value for a declared class?

Comment: Good point! I suppose the runtime code does that anyway.

Comment: Haha, that should be the answer!

Comment: is the default value for class member 'undefined' as well or it is null?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your program attempts to perform two mutually contradictory tasks.

1. It tries to *declare* that a class exists but is actually *implemented* elsewhere/otherwise.
2. It tries to *define* that implementation.

You need to determine which of these tasks you wish to perform and adjust your program accordingly by removing either the initializer or the `declare` modifier.

Answer (score 29):

Try removing declare from your class definition. By using declare it will define a class type. The type is only defined, and shouldn't have an implementation.

```
class Foo extends Bar {
    foo: number = 60
}
```

Comment: I'm not the downvoter but I would suspect it is due to your assumption

Answer (score -6):

You need a constructor in order to set default values to class property.

Try this:

```
declare class Foo extends Bar {
    foo: number;
  constructor(){
   this.foo = 60;
  }  
}
```

**UPDATE:**
After taking a closer look at your code snippet i noticed you are using the keyword declare, doing so, you just defined a class type and this one **requires no implementation.**

**UPDATE 2:**
A class constructor is not necessary for this, you may initialize your properties with or without one.

If you remove the keyword declare it should work fine.

```
class Foo extends Bar {
        foo: number;
      constructor(){
       this.foo = 60;
      }  
    }
```

Comment: "You need a constructor in order to set default values to class property." That is entirely false

Comment: Yes, you actually don't need a constructor for this, just my choice of class design. I'm updating this because i don't want people over reacting over nothing haha

Comment: How can it be reacting over nothing? You make a false, irrelevant claim.